# tikz--center a block diagram and a matrix below block diagram with custom spacing--pdf previewing under TexStudio

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, texstudio, tikz-matrix

I would like to create a block diagram in tikz and to center a matrix below the block diagram.  When I use the following, the block diagram snaps to the left and the matrix snaps to the right.  What's wrong here?  Also, how do I control the vertical distance between the diagram and the matrix?

```
\documentclass[crop,tizk]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
    \node [draw, shape=rectangle] (stage1) {Stage 1};
    \node [draw, shape=rectangle] (stage2) [right of= stage1]  {Stage 2};
    \draw (stage1) -- (stage2);
    \node[align = center, anchor=south, matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm] at (current page.south)
    {
                $y=x$ & &   \begin{tabular}{c}
                                         11\\
                                         12
                                     \end{tabular}  \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}
```

OK.  I discovered that this is an issue with the TexStudio pdf previwer which gives:

[image]

When I open the pdf directly, I get what I wanted:

[image]

Why does the TexStudio pdf previewer give different rendering than the actual pdf file?

Comment: Please take the time to copy a complete Minimal Working Example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{docoument}` so that members could copy/paste it and see what happens without having to figure out what you are currently using. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SebGlav Question amended.